# Request null in Servlet Filter

Tags: java, xml, jsp, servlets, filter

I've an issue that'll nearly make go mad. I've declared a servlet Filter in web.xml in order to use it to encode file name (I want to get rid of accents to prevent any problems in the future for upload/download files). The thing is before I used the Servlet Filter, I've been using Request parameters normally. Now that I want to use the Servlet Filter for the purpose explained before, when I try to used the request inside the Filter, oddly enough, I get an empty request. I searched for days seekin' some solutions, in vain sadly.

I put down my servlet filter declaration in web.xml file and the servlet filter doFilter code.

**web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>Encoding Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.util.encoding.EncodingCharsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>   
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>Encoding Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/AppUpload</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

**Servlet Filter Class**

```
 public final void doFilter(final ServletRequest req, final ServletResponse resp, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

              HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;

//            if (req.getCharacterEncoding() == null && this.encoding != null) {
//                    
//                     String oldFile = req.getParameter("fileName");
//                     
//                     String newFile= Normalizer.decompose(oldFile,false,0).replaceAll("\\p{InCombiningDiacriticalMarks}+", ""); 
//                     
//                     req.setAttribute("fileName", newFile);
//                     
//                     req.setCharacterEncoding(encoding);
//            }

            Map<String, String[]> parameters = request.getParameterMap();
            for(String parameter : parameters.keySet()) {
                System.out.println(parameter);
            }

//            Enumeration<String> parameterNames = req.getParameterNames();
//            
//            while (parameterNames.hasMoreElements()) {
//               
//                 
//                
//                            String paramName = parameterNames.nextElement();
//                
//                            System.out.println(paramName);
//                
//                            System.out.println("n");
//                
//                 
//                
//                            String[] paramValues = req.getParameterValues(paramName);
//                
//                            for (int i = 0; i < paramValues.length; i++) {
//                
//                                String paramValue = paramValues[i];
//                
//                                System.out.println("t" + paramValue);
//                
//                                System.out.println("n");
//                
//                            }
//
//            }
            chain.doFilter(req, resp);

    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be there would be a redirection from AppUpload to other Servlet!!!

Answer (score 0):

you hit url by this `<url-pattern>/AppUpload</url-pattern> ?`

I mean from `AppUpload` page? ...something like `localhost:port/AppUpload` ?

if its not then you may write  `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` in `web.xml`.

and check it from any page from your web app.

Comment: AppUpload is the servlet name in the web.xml

`<servlet>
        <description>Upload Java</description>
        <display-name>Upload Java</display-name>
        <servlet-name>AppUpload</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.nexans.common.utils.FileUploadServlet</servlet-class>`